# Bootstrap 3 navs, dropdowns, tabs (still) not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen other posts regarding this topic and none of the offered solutions have fixed it for me. My tab nav and dropdown menus don't seem to work in IE8.

I've tried older versions (1.11.3) of jquery. The html5shiv.js and respond.js are in my header. Nav dropdowns, tabbed navigation doesn't seem to work.

Comment: won't get much help without providing your code and a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Sorry, first post. There's a live example here: http://www.dtn.com/trading. Dropdown, modals, tabs don't function in IE8.  Thanks!

Comment: tried in IE8 browser mode within IE10 and couldn't replicate. Maybe someone else with a working copy of real IE8 will check it. Any errors thrown?

Comment: I couldn't replicate running within IE10 either, only when running IE8 stand alone. I tested in virtual machines with both Vista and Win7 running IE8. There are javascript errors though they seem to happen with the bootstrap site 'navs' section as well where the sample spilldowns work.

Comment: Those errors are the critical part likely

Comment: That's what I initially thought but the same errors occur on the Bootstrap sample page that works fine. They seem to be benign errors from the Bootstrap source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the wrong linked older version of jquery. I had linked to 1.11.1 and not 1.11.3. Linking to 1.11.3 resolved the issue.